# PHP: get next date based on fixed base date

Tags: php, date, datetime, date-arithmetic

is there a way in PHP to get the next date(s) using a 4-week interval from a given date ?

**Example:**

My start date is Friday, Jan 03, 2014 and my interval is every 4 weeks from that date. 
What I am looking for is the next date (or dates, if possible) from the current date that matches this 4-week interval. 
In the above example this would be Friday, May 23, 2014 (then June 20, 2014, July 18, 2014 etc.).

I know I can get the current date as follows: `$today = date('Y-m-d');`

and I could probably set the start date like this: `$start = date('2014-01-03');`

but I don't know how to calculate the interval and how to find out the next matching date(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read up on the DateTime classes, specifically [DatePeriod](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateperiod.construct.php) and [DateInterval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php):

```
$start = new DateTime('2014-01-03');
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('4 weeks');
$end = new DateTime('2015-12-31');

$occurrences = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

foreach ($occurrences as $occurrence) {
    echo $occurrence->format('Y-m-d') . PHP_EOL;
}
```

`DatePeriod` takes a start date and a `DateInterval` and allows you traverse over the object to get all dates within the boundaries using the given interval. The cut off can be either a set number of cycles (so the next 10 dates) or an end date (like above), even if the end date is not one of the dates the interval falls on (it will stop below it).  Or you can use an [8601 interval notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_intervals) string (which sounds so much fun, huh?), but I'm pretty shaky on that.

Comment: Based on the above comments I chose this one. This works and the explanations are awesome - thanks a lot 1

Answer (score 0):

If 4-week interval means 7 x 4 = 28 days, you can obtain the "next date" by:

```
$today = new DateTime();
$next_date = $today->add(new DateInterval('P28D'));
$next_next_date = $next_date->add(new DateInterval('P28D'));
$next_next_next_date = $next_next_date->add(new DateInterval('P28D'));
```

And if you want to calculate more "next dates", you can repeat the `add()` to repetitively add 28 days to your date.

Note: Beside using `P28D`, you can use `P4W`, which means 4 weeks.

---

While some answers may suggest using `strtotime()`, I find the object-oriented approach more structured. However, `DateInterval` is only available after PHP >= 5.3.0 (while `DateTime` is available after PHP >= 5.2.0)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply ! Yes, this means 7x4 days. So the above would give me the next date. Could I also extend this to get for example the next 3 matching dates ? + how is the above based on my start date ?

Comment: Updated the answer. No clue how should I name the dates. Forgive me of the variable names.

Comment: Thanks for the updates ! - Would this add 28 days to today or to the given start date (which is what I need) ? To explain: What I want is to add the 4 weeks to the start date and then check from now for the next date(s) matching this interval.

Comment: Note that by DateTime.add() the original (here $today) variable is changed, too!

Comment: @Mike given start date will be added by 28 days. You can try it yourself & play around.

Comment: This is not correct in that the OP wants the intervals to be added to `$start` not `$now`...

Comment: PHP 5.2 is no longer supported as of 3 years ago. We need to encourage supported solutions, not legacy-safe ones.

Answer (score 0):

You could use strtotime()

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('now +4 weeks'));
```

UPDATED:

```
$start = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2014-01-03 +4 weeks'));
echo $start;
```

You could also run this in a for loop to get the next 6 or more dates. For example:

```
$Date = "2014-01-03";
$Int = 6;
for($i=0; $i<$Int; $i++){
    $Date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('{$Date} +4 weeks'));
    echo $Date;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What I want is to add the 4 weeks to the start date and then check from now for the next date(s) matching this interval.